# Cannot connect to postgres installed on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, postgresql

I installed the [Bitnami Django stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack) which included PostgreSQL 8.4.

When I run `psql -U postgres` I get the following error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

PG is definitely running and the `pg_hba.conf` file looks like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            CIDR-ADDRESS            METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

What gives?

"Proof" that pg is running:

```
root@assaf-desktop:/home/assaf# ps axf | grep postgres
14338 ?        S      0:00 /opt/djangostack-1.3-0/postgresql/bin/postgres -D /opt/djangostack-1.3-0/postgresql/data -p 5432
14347 ?        Ss     0:00  \_ postgres: writer process                                                                        
14348 ?        Ss     0:00  \_ postgres: wal writer process                                                                    
14349 ?        Ss     0:00  \_ postgres: autovacuum launcher process                                                           
14350 ?        Ss     0:00  \_ postgres: stats collector process                                                               
15139 pts/1    S+     0:00              \_ grep --color=auto postgres
root@assaf-desktop:/home/assaf# netstat -nltp | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14338/postgres  
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      14338/postgres  
root@assaf-desktop:/home/assaf#
```

Answer (score 3):

I use following workaround so both clients should be happy:

```
sudo ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

Comment: This worked for me! :)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that /tmp/* wont survive reboots on many systems. Using "psql -h /var/run/postgresql -U postgres" worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

At a guess you're using the system version of the `psql` command, which will look for the postgres unix domain sockets in `/var/run/postgresql` and the third party postgres you are using has been configured to put them somewhere else.

The easiest solution is probably to use `/opt/djangostack-1.3-0/postgresql/bin/psql` instead, assuming that there is one, as it will presumably look in the correct place for the unix sockets.

Otherwise, you need to look at the `unix_socket_directory` setting in `postgresql.conf` but it's quite likely that will be commented out and it is using a compiled in default.

Comment: Thanks, but using the other psql binary yielded the same results.

Comment: The you need to checkout `postgresql.conf` as I suggested to see where it is putting the unix socket - either that or use `lsof` on the running postgres server process.

Comment: Also instead of using the full path to the psql binary in the BitNami installation you can first load the BitNami environment. Execute `/opt/djangostack-1.3-0/use_djangostack` then if you execute `psql` or `python` the binaries from the BitNami installation will be taken.

Answer (score 0):

The error message refers to a Unix-domain socket, so you need to tweak your `netstat` invocation to not exclude them.  So try it without the option `-t`:

```
netstat -nlp | grep 5432
```

I would guess that the server is actually listening on the socket `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` rather than the `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432` that your client is attempting to connect to.  This is a typical problem when using hand-compiled or third-party PostgreSQL packages on Debian or Ubuntu, because the source default for the Unix-domain socket directory is `/tmp` but the Debian packaging changes it to `/var/run/postgresql`.

Possible workarounds:

- Use the clients supplied by your third-party package (call `/opt/djangostack-1.3-0/postgresql/bin/psql`).  Possibly deinstall the Ubuntu-supplied packages altogether (might be difficult because of other reverse dependencies).
- Fix the socket directory of the third-party package to be compatible with Debian/Ubuntu.
- Use `-h localhost` to connect via TCP/IP instead.
- Use `-h /tmp` or equivalent `PGHOST` setting to point to the right directory.
- Don't use third-party packages.

Answer (score 0):

Restart postgresql by using the command

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart postgresql
```

This worked for me

[image]